# Translate into a formula using quantifiers

Tags: quantifiers, logic-translation

Let B(x) be “x is a bird”, F(x) be “x has feathers”, and Y(x) be “x can fly”.
Then translate into a formula using quantifiers: Some things that can fly are not birds.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to this site! Your question looks as though it is copied from a textbook.  This is a site where people can answer your mathematical questions, not do your mathematical tasks or assignments for you.  Tell us what you have tried, where it is that you are stuck, and ask a precise question (notice that your post contains no question, just the description of a task).

Comment: Would it be  ∃x(C(x)→F(x)) ?

Comment: Is that the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to say, is that there exists some thing that flies and is not a bird. Using quantifiers this is $\exists x ( Y(x)\land\neg B(x)) $.